# Unable to create a Julia file using Jupyter Notebook in Chrome browser

Tags: julia

I am trying to write Julia using Jupyter Notebook in Google Chrome browser but when I click on New, I do not get the option of creating a new Julia file (shown in the screenshot). I have already added the package- IJulia. What am I missing?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this before. Doing a `Pkg.build("IJulia")` and then restart Jupyter fixed it for me.

EDIT: corrected capitalisation

Comment: `Pkg.build("IJulia")`